# ng2-completer search icon closes my autocomplete

Tags: html, angular

I am using ng2-completer in my Angular2 application. It works fine in desktop browser but when I view it in my mobile browser I get the virtual keyboard of ipad and when I click search on it the autocomplete closes.

How do I fix this bug?

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer

Comment: It's a bug in this plugin. You see here : https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/issues/270. I could try to fix this issue tonight

Comment: should be fixed in ng2-completer latest version.